# Regex till first match C# and cut the string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Hi Regex gurus of this site, i have an issue trying to write regex which return first part of message till first match. I'm programming in C# language and using parameters `(?is)`

My current regex is: `:(?<Tag>[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{0,}):(?<Value>.*?)(?=:75:|:75E:|:79:)`

My sample string is:

```
:20:gtregeeg.::()(*&(*&(ERW
:70:fdaksjfdjkahfdkahkdahjkdafda+++----
- :20:aslfkjdklasjdlsafjkdsaf.\[[][^%$#%*$^#(
:75: asdfasdfsasfd812349798759*&)(*)((_
.5697.dsaasdfasfa()()(2435325&^&*&()*
:79:afdfdasfdas(*(&*(&)(__+-*-**--+
:75E:adfasf-++++***/*/-/-*/*++...
:20:dafsdfadfasd_+_+)((*&&^*
:75:sdafassfafdfadsafdadfaaf204392-395(**(&(&()*)
:::.....------------+-**--
```

How to match everything till first tag match `:75:` because if there are more tags in string text it continues to match. I need to match only till first found tag `:75:` and i don't care what follows up next. Tried to search this site for particular solution and what tried nothing helped i got the same answer that if tag occurs further in text it still matches. Thanks for help.

**I have update my regex, when multiple positive look ahead so at the end `.*$` doesn't help, it still produces whole string, but my desired output should be only first match,  till first met on of tags:**

```
:20:gtregeeg.::()(*&(*&(ERW
:70:fdaksjfdjkahfdkahkdahjkdafda+++----
- :20:aslfkjdklasjdlsafjkdsaf.\[[][^%$#%*$^#(
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Expected output is till first tag :75: all symbols from begining. And don't search anymore tags :75: . If from given example only this part of message: 
`:20:gtregeeg.::()(*&(*&(ERW
:70:fdaksjfdjkahfdkahkdahjkdafda+++----
- :20:aslfkjdklasjdlsafjkdsaf.\[[][^%$#%*$^#(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that will do it the way you expect:

```
:(?<Tag>[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{0,}):(?<Value>.*?)(?=:75:).*$
```

`.*$` will consume all the text you have up to the end, so the first capture group will have the text from the `Tag` to the first `:75:`. This works with `Singleline` and `Ignorecase` options.

Tested in Expresso:

[image]

To grab the whole beginning part of the string up to the first `:75:`, you should add another capturing `begin` group: `(?si)(?<begin>:(?<Tag>[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{0,}):(?<Value>.*?))(?=:75:).*$`.

Here is a [program showing the captured groups](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_csharp_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMa2R0ZjY4OTFNUHM):

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var rgx = new Regex(@"(?si)(?<begin>:(?<Tag>[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{0,}):(?<Value>.*?))(?=:75:).*$");
        var str = @":20:gtregeeg.::()(*&(*&(ERW
:70:fdaksjfdjkahfdkahkdahjkdafda+++----
- :20:aslfkjdklasjdlsafjkdsaf.\[[][^%$#%*$^#(
:75: asdfasdfsasfd812349798759*&)(*)((_
.5697.dsaasdfasfa()()(2435325&^&*&()*
:79:afdfdasfdas(*(&*(&)(__+-*-**--+
:75E:adfasf-++++***/*/-/-*/*++...
:20:dafsdfadfasd_+_+)((*&&^*
:75:sdafassfafdfadsafdadfaaf204392-395(**(&(&()*)
:::.....------------+-**--";
        var mtch = rgx.Match(str);

        // Show our captured values and first match
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Value:\n{0}\n========================================\nTag:\n{1}=============================\nBeginning of string up to first `:75:`:\n{2}", mtch.Groups["Tag"].Value, mtch.Groups["Value"].Value, mtch.Groups["begin"].Value));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you stribizhev it does the trick, but somehow regexhero.net matches all the text, but when watching in groups it does return the value as i expected. Thanks !

Comment: Yes, as I wrote, the value will be captured alright into `Tag` and `Value`, just we need to consume all the characters so that no other match is returned.

Comment: Thanks for explanation stribizhev, so if anything not in groups it won't be captured, that's nice, didn't know about this thing. So i guess regex will change drastically if not using parameter SIngline and Ignorecase ? Is it possible to provide example in this case from you ?

Comment: You need to catch newlines, you should use singleline mode to force `.` to match newlines. Or, you should replace dots with [\s\S]. In order not to use ignorecase option, you need to use [a-zA-Z].

Comment: Hi stribizhev i don't know if you programming on C# but i hit the wall, the regexp in C# Regex class doesn't do the job, any thoughts ? Or maybe there is other solution to cut it ?

Comment: Did you set the options? You can use `var rgx = new Regex(@"(?si):(?<Tag>[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{0,}):(?<Value>.*?)(?=:75:).*$");` or `var rgx = new Regex(@":(?<Tag>[0-9]{1,}[a-z]{0,}):(?<Value>.*?)(?=:75:).*$", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Ignorecase);`

Comment: Yes i did, doesn't help. Well i heard one thing that in Windows Server .net framework different than in local PC for users, and this maybe causing problems ? Because it still captures all string not skipping anything just whole till the end.

Comment: The match will be the whole string, because we need to consume all the string to return one match. You want the tag and value values, right? If not, you must tell us what exactly you want to do. Are you replacing? What will be the final result?

Comment: Yes i want to take tag and value till first match and that's it, it doesn't atter what goes next or there are atching tags, i need till first emt amtch to cut, yes question is good. All type of regex testers shows that regex is good, but when comes to C# it doesn't do the trick, please see the [link](http://i.imgur.com/bGUz0Ki.jpg), any thoughts ?

Comment: Please check the answer update. Please let me know what string you need to get as **the final result**, if it is still not working the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks it works, i understood how to use correctly in my code, appreciate for your hard effort !

Answer (score 0):

You could just do: `YOUR_TEXT.Split(new string [] {":75:"})[0]`

If I were going to make it into a function I would probably do something like:

```
public static FindFirstOccurance Tuple<bool,String> (string input, 
    string search)
{
    if(String.IsNull(input)){throw new ArgumentException("Input is null");}
    if(String.IsNull(search)){throw new ArgumentException("search is null");}


   var parts = input.Split(new string[]{search});

   return new Tuple<bool,string>(parts > 1, parts[0]);

}
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, by any chance there is other solution ? I would like to do that with Regex, i think this task becomes a little bit hard when to use regex.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for your effort stribizhev  solution works perfectly for me. But definetely i will try to use yours too if needed in some cases !

Answer (score 0):

If tested your sample data on regex101.com with this regex

```
:(?<Tag>\d+[a-z]*):(?<Value>.*?)(?=:75:)
```

which is essentially the same as your proposal with the addional trailing colon at the end of the value group, and it's working, not extending into further text. Should work for you too. Any other sample data which doesn't work for you?

Comment: This will return 2 matches.

Comment: Yes this returns two matches.

Comment: Sorry to disagree: I've compared your expected output from your comment 1:1 to the output on regex101.com and it matches 100%! tag group is [1-3], value group is [4-114]. Have you tested the regex within your code, or on the site? If within your code then the regex machine is acting differently from PCRE standard. In that case, sorry.

Comment: Well you right regex101 acts differently, even my regex returns correct value, regexhero.net built on .net library and shows up differently, so in c# language your regex will cause error in PHP it won't, but in my case for C# stribizhev answer is the case. Thanks for effort. Every language has different things built in for regex.